# Pandas group-by date range & different calculations on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having troubles with grouping a pandas df by time range and different calculations by column:

Let's take following df:

```
           date          identifier    value_1    value_2
0     05.07.2018 16:35       A           10          0
1     05.07.2018 16:36       B           20          1
2     05.07.2018 16:37       A           20          2
3     05.07.2018 16:39       B           30          1
4     05.07.2018 16:40       A           40          3
5     05.07.2018 16:41       B           20          2
6     05.07.2018 16:41       A           30          1
7     05.07.2018 16:42       B           50          2
8     05.07.2018 16:43       B           20          3
9     05.07.2018 16:44       A           20          1
```

As a result I need a df, which is grouped by time in 5 mins intervals and by identifier, with the average of value_1 and the sum of value_2:

```
           date          identifier    value_1    value_2
0     05.07.2018 16:35       A           15          2
1     05.07.2018 16:35       B           25          2
2     05.07.2018 16:40       A           30          5
3     05.07.2018 16:40       B           30          7
```

How can I do this the most efficient way in pandas?

THX & BR from Vienna

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Grouper.html), and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), after setting your `date` column to `datetime` with the proper format:

```
# Set date to datetime format. I'm assuming it's day.month.year in your original dataframe
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

new_df = (df.groupby(['identifier', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5min')])
          .agg({'value_1':'mean', 'value_2':'sum'}))

>>> new_df
                                value_1  value_2
identifier date                                 
A          2018-07-05 16:35:00       15        2
           2018-07-05 16:40:00       30        5
B          2018-07-05 16:35:00       25        2
           2018-07-05 16:40:00       30        7
```

If you want the same format as your desired output in your post, you can use this to sort:

```
new_df.reset_index().sort_values(['date','identifier'])

  identifier                date  value_1  value_2
0          A 2018-07-05 16:35:00       15        2
2          B 2018-07-05 16:35:00       25        2
1          A 2018-07-05 16:40:00       30        5
3          B 2018-07-05 16:40:00       30        7
```